# i use the 'angular-froala-wysiwyg',but menu bar reduced

Tags: angular, wysiwyg

I build a new project for angular and introduced 'angular-froala-wysiwyg', the menu is all right ,bug I introduced '`angular-froala-wysiwyg`' in my angular project, the menu is few.
this is new project's menu:
[image]

and this is my project:
[image]

Comment: Please be more specific, what's the question?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).